# How to position dynamically repeated element at bottom of div or repeat "upwards"?

Tags: html, css

I am repeating an element n times (with angular).

HTML:

```
<div class="card d-flex align-items-center; height: 30vh;"
    <div id="bar" *ngFor="let i of Arr(num).fill(1)"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 35px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red , green);
}
```

It works and repeats the bar num times.

My problem is it repeats starting at the top going down. i.e. if num is 5 then there is a huge gap beneath the last bar and the bottom of the card. if num is 10 then there is a smaller gap.

I need it upside down - i.e. the gap to be above the bars, not beneath - repeating starting at the bottom going up (or so it should appear).

I have tried setting the position of the bar div to absolute and from the bottom. I have tried setting the parent div to relative as well as I saw that in another question. I have looked into transforming but couldn't get that to work as it's a relative thing along the axes. I have tried with Flex as well and put flex-column in the parent with ms-auto in the child but that didn't work. I just couldn't get the few bars to move downward at all.

How do I set it so that the bottom-most bar is at the bottom of the parent?

Comment: [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) should do the trick

Comment: I thought so too but was not able to get it right. Could you give an example perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a [flex box layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) using [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).  For example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- your repeating elements -->
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

I don't know the specifics, but your classes like `d-flex align-items-center` look like a Bootstrap(-ish?) layout toolset.  (My Bootstrap experience is probably a couple versions out of date.)  If that toolset has a class for `flex-direction: column-reverse` then you should just be able to add that to your container.  (Or `row-reverse`?  I may be making assumptions about your layout here.)

Comment: can't believe that was so easy and I couldn't get it. thanks!